# How to get gem full list with Ruby code?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I want get gem full lists, and do some analytics!
But I only know command `gem list --remote`.

Answer (score 1):

This returns you an array of Ruby gems:

```
`gem list --remote`.split(/\n/)
```